# react-table, useState hook within table results to default value although set before

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table

I am using react-table to display fetched data within a table. You also have different buttons within that table to interact with the data such as deleting an entry, or updating its data (toggle button to approve a submitted row).

The data is being fetched in an initial `useEffect(() => fetchBars(), [])` and then being passed to useTable by passing it through useMemo as suggested in the react-table documentation. Now I can click on the previously mentioned buttons within the table to delete an entry but when I try to access the data (`bars`) that has been set within `fetchBars()`it returns the default state used by `useState()` which is an empty array []. What detail am I missing? I want to use the bars state in order to filter deleted rows for example and thus make the table reactive, without having to re-fetch on every update.

When calling `console.log(bars)` within `updateMyData()` it displays the fetched data correctly, however calling `console.log(bars)` within `handleApprovedUpdate()` yields to the empty array, why so? Do I need to pass the `handleApprovedUpdate()` into the cell as well as the useTable hook as well?

```js
const EditableCell = ({
    value: initialValue,
    row: { index },
    column: { id },
    row: row,
    updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
  }: CellValues) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
  
    const onChange = (e: any) => {
      setValue(e.target.value)
    }
 
    const onBlur = () => {
      updateMyData(index, id, value)
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setValue(initialValue)
    }, [initialValue])
  
    return <EditableInput value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
}

const Dashboard: FC<IProps> = (props) => {
    const [bars, setBars] = useState<Bar[]>([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const COLUMNS: any = [
        {
            Header: () => null,
            id: 'approver',
            disableSortBy: true,
            Cell: (props :any) => {
                return (
                    <input
                        id="approved"
                        name="approved"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={props.cell.row.original.is_approved}
                        onChange={() => handleApprovedUpdate(props.cell.row.original.id)}
                    />
                )
            }
        }
    ];

    const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
      () => ({
        Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
        Cell: EditableCell,
      }), [])

    const updateMyData = (rowIndex: any, columnId: any, value: any) => {
        let barUpdate;
        setBars(old =>
            old.map((row, index) => {
                if (index === rowIndex) {
                    barUpdate = {
                        ...old[rowIndex],
                        [columnId]: value,
                    }
                    return barUpdate;
                }
                return row
            })
        )
        if(barUpdate) updateBar(barUpdate)
    }

    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
    const data = useMemo(() => bars, [bars]);
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: columns,
        data: data,
        initialState: {

        },
        defaultColumn,
        updateMyData
    }, useFilters, useSortBy, useExpanded );

    const fetchBars = () => {
         axios
            .get("/api/allbars",
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
                    }
                }, )
            .then(response => {
                setBars(response.data)
            })
            .catch(() => {
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBars()
    }, []);

    const handleApprovedUpdate = (barId: number): void => {
        const approvedUrl = `/api/bar/approved?id=${barId}`
        setLoading(true)
        axios
            .put(
                approvedUrl, {},
                {
                    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")}
                }
            )
            .then(() => {
                const updatedBar: Bar | undefined = bars.find(bar => bar.id === barId);
                if(updatedBar == null) {
                    setLoading(false)
                    return;
                }

                updatedBar.is_approved = !updatedBar?.is_approved
                setBars(bars.map(bar => (bar.id === barId ? updatedBar : bar)))
                setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setLoading(false)
                renderToast(error.response.request.responseText);
            });
    };

    const renderTable = () => {
        const {
            getTableProps,
            getTableBodyProps,
            headerGroups,
            rows, 
            prepareRow
        } = tableInstance;

        return(
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                    <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                    </span>{' '}
                                    <span>
                                        {column.isSorted ? column.isSortedDesc ? ' ▼' : ' ▲' : ''}
                                    </span>
                                    <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : <Spacer/>}</div>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {rows.map(row => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        const rowProps = {...row.getRowProps()}
                        delete rowProps.role;
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment {...rowProps}>
                                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return (
                                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </tr>
                                {row.isExpanded ? renderRowSubComponent({row}): null}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )})
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing stale values within `handleApprovedUpdate` because it's capturing `bars` the first time the component is rendered, then never being updated since you're using it inside `COLUMNS`, which is wrapped with a `useMemo` with an empty dependencies array.

This is difficult to visualize in your example because it's filtered through a few layers of indirection, so here's a contrived example:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [bars, setBars] = useState([]);

  const logBars = () => {
    console.log(bars);
  };

  const memoizedLogBars = useMemo(() => logBars, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBars([1, 2, 3]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={memoizedLogBars}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
}
```

Clicking the button will *always* log `[]`, even though `bars` is immediately updated inside the `useEffect` to `[1, 2, 3]`. When you memoize `logBars` with `useMemo` and an empty dependencies array, you're telling React "use the value of `bars` you can currently see, it will never change (I promise)".

You can resolve this by adding `bars` to the dependency array for `useMemo`.

```js
const memoizedLogBars = useMemo(() => logBars, [bars]);
```

Now, clicking the button should correctly log the most recent value of `bars`.

In your component, you should be able to resolve your issue by changing `columns` to

```js
const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [bars]);
```

You can read more about stale values in hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function). You may also want to consider adding [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) to your project setup so you can identify issues like this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and correct answer! Installed the eslint hooks package right away.

Comment: great solved the problem